# C++11 Uniform Initialization and function overloading

Tags: c++, c++11, overloading, uniform-initialization

Simple program:

```
void f(const std::string& s);
void f(const char* p);
f({});
```

Why clang calls `f((const char*)nullptr)`? I've expected compiler warning about ambiguous call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is covered in the draft C++11 standard section `13.3.3.1.5` *[over.ics.list]* which says:

> Otherwise, if the parameter type is not a class:
>
> [...]
>
> - if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion.
>     [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   void f(int);
>   f( { } ); // OK: identity conversion
>   ```
>
> —end example ]

and so an identity conversion would be better than a constructor call.

The reason why we get a nullptr is because it is value initializing the pointer. From section `8.5.4` *[dcl.init.list]*:

> List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.
>     [ Example:
>
>   ```
>   int** pp {}; // initialized to null pointer
>   ```
>
> —end example ]